# How to get cell of array input as string in inputdlg?

Tags: matlab

(R2016b:Matlab Version)
I want to take user input in inputdlg as string and then a cell of array of all the input strings into one variable

My code is:

```
  prompt = {'Input the number of Criterion','Input short name of criterion'};
  dlg_title = 'Alternative Evauation';
  num_lines = 1;
  defaultans = {'3','{Criterion1,Criterion2,Criterion3}'};
  answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);
```

although I am able to read `number of Criterion` as

```
  n=str2num(answer{1})
```

but when I try to read the `short name of criteria` as

```
  str=answer{2}
```

then instead of reading `str`as cell of array 
`'Criterion1', 'Criterion2', 'Criterion3'` separately, it reads as `Criterion1Criterion2Criterion3`
I want variable `str` as

```
 str={'Criterion1', 'Criterion2', 'Criterion3'...}
```

there is no limit on inputting the `number of criterion`, it may be 5 or 7, depending upon the User, so accordingly `name of criterion` will increase

Comment: You can try to use [`strsplit`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) or use two input dialogs: one for the number and one for the actual conditions for which you provide as many input fields as requested in the first input dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing is that `inputdlg` return a **single string** for each input variable. you can use `strsplit` to split this string into several criterion names:

```
prompt = {'Input the number of Criterion','Input short name of criterion'};
dlg_title = 'Alternative Evauation';
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = {'3','Criterion1,Criterion2,Criterion3'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);
% get number of criterions
n = str2num(answer{1});
% get criterion default names (cell array of size [1 n])
defStr = cellfun(@(name,num) [name num2str(num)],...
    repmat({'Criterion'},[1 n]),num2cell(1:n),'UniformOutput',0);
% get user supplied criterion names and split by commas
temp = strsplit(answer{2},',');
str = defStr;
% assign user's names instead of default ones
str(1:numel(temp)) = temp;
```

Comment: Awesome...Not only now user input works but you have also taken care of the default names....Thank you very much!!!